# exec-maven-plugin with sources and compiled files

Tags: maven

I am trying to use exec goal to compile something that is not java using pom.xml. I am using a proprietary compiler that can either produce source files or compiled (obfuscated) files.

I am using two separate directories and the exec-maven-plugin. So I am having two executions:

```
<execution>
    <id>make-sources</id>
    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target-sources</workingDirectory>
        <executable>makecode</executable>
        <arguments>
        ..
            <argument>is_source=1</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
<execution>
    <id>make-compiled</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}/target</workingDirectory>
        <executable>makecode</executable>
        <arguments>
        ..
            <argument>is_source=0</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

This pom is then moved to artifactory from jenkins where it is being run. As the next step it is using build-helper-maven-plugin:

```
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-base</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <!-- Add the main artifact -->
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${basedir}/target/product-${project.version}.tar.gz</file>
                                    <type>tgz</type>
                                    <classifier>compiled</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>${basedir}/target-sources/product-${project.version}.tar.gz</file>
                                    <type>tgz</type>
                                    <classifier>sources</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
```

When jenkins finishes the job it creates two artifacts, one product-{ver}-sources.tar.gz and one product-{ver}-compiled.tar.gz. Although I'd expect that the tar.gz are different, the files inside are the same. Is package the phase that I am supposed to create those tar.gz files or should I be using something different for sources tar.gz?